# Разделение задач между фрагментами и активити

Tags: android

В процессе изучения возник вопрос по поводу *разделения задач* между активити и ее фрагментами.

Припустим есть одно активити и оно содержит один фрагмент! У меня должна выполнятся работа с БД. Даные выборки должны отображаться на фрагменте. Также данные таблицы БД должны изменяться из фрагмента!

Какие задачи должна выполнять активити, а какие фрагмент? И какого рода задачи, на практике, полагаются на активность

Comment: в вашем описании не вижу смысл в одном фрагменте, делайте всё из под activity, но если вы собираетесь что-то добавлять дальше, то опишите это в вопросе, станет понятней.